# Is there any viber PPA?

Tags: 15.10, repository, viber

I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 and I'm looking for a viber ppa for automatic updates. I've already installed viber via .deb file from the official website but ppa will be better.
Thanks for the answers!

Comment: AFAIK, there's no PPA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately they don't have any **PPA** available. Viber Support Team will sure on this:

Download Viber (*.deb) file [here](http://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/viber.deb).

```
 cd ~/Downloads/
 sudo dpkg -i viber.deb
```

**Run**

Type Viber in dash. Click the launcher icon.
For Gnome, go to Applications -> Internet -> Viber

**How to uninstall**

```
sudo apt-get remove viber
```